# Ionic : LocalFileSystem is not defined in Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am not able to get the cordova file system to work. I have a project with the following dependencies:
In `app.js` I define a dependency on a controller module:

```
exampleApp.controller("FileController", function($scope, $ionicLoading) {

$scope.download = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Loading...'
    });
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
        fs.root.getDirectory(
            "ExampleProject",
            {
                create: true
            },
            function(dirEntry) {
                dirEntry.getFile(
                    "test.png", 
                    {
                        create: true, 
                        exclusive: false
                    }, 
                    function gotFileEntry(fe) {
                        var p = fe.toURL();
                        fe.remove();
                        ft = new FileTransfer();
                        ft.download(
                            encodeURI("http://ionicframework.com/img/ionic-logo-blog.png"),
                            p,
                            function(entry) {
                                $ionicLoading.hide();
                                $scope.imgFile = entry.toURL();
                            },
                            function(error) {
                                $ionicLoading.hide();
                                alert("Download Error Source -> " + error.source);
                            },
                            false,
                            null
                        );
                    }, 
                    function() {
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                        console.log("Get file failed");
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    },
    function() {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log("Request for filesystem failed");
    });
}

});
```

What I then get is:

LocalFileSystem is not defined

Also, requestFileSystem is undefined. What could be the reason for this behavior?

I am using cordova 4.1.2 and ionic 1.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install cordova file plugin to use these functionalities, add plugin to your project by this command:
`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file`

**Note:** Cordova file system is supposed to work with real devices or emulators, not browsers.

Comment: are you testing it on browser? or real device?

Comment: cordova file system is not supposed to work with your computer system, these are to access file system of real devices os. These will work if you test them on real device or emulator.

Comment: yes, now its work but file pdf cannot show it. how can show it ?

Comment: sorry i have no idea about that, may be you should post separate question for that .I could only help with making plugin functional.